# Flex and source folders in bin-debug

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air

Is there a way to avoid the copy of the empty folders, based on the current source library structure, in bin-debug folder?
I'm using Flex 3.2
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Flex Builder in the compiler options section of the project properties there should be a Copy non-embedded files to output folder checkbox.

Comment: Thanks, that's nice, but how to include specific folders? I'm using Flex Builder for Air projects, and I need to include some assets in the .air package. If I disable 'Copy non-embedded files' I cannot include any extra files/folders

Comment: Unfortunately, Flex/Flash Builder does not provide per-file control of copying non-embedded files. It's all or nothing.

Comment: could you use the html-template (Properties -> ActionScript Compiler -> HTML Wrapper) for copying files for your project?